# I want a listener on Storing Bitmap Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-internal-storage

**Storing Large Bitmap in internal Storage**
I need to know when a large bitmap is stored so i can pass that path to other function. Right now i am handling it handler post delayed so it shows half portion of image some part on large bitmap 
So if there is any listener which can tell that your image is 100% stored then only i pass that path to another function

Answer (score 0):

Here is code example from Android documentation:

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

So instead downloading do storing action.